# How can i derive values list of values from list of either using flatmap for fold?

Tags: scala

im trying to convert a scala list of eithers, as such:

```
List(Left(3),Left(4),Left(1),Left(5))
```

Into a either of a list Either[List[Int],Int] like this?
Left(3,4,1,5)
Only using flatmap, map or fold?
ive been hammering at it for a while now and can simply not make it work

Comment: What are the rules? If all are lefts accumulate them? If all are rights combine them? What if there are mixed values? How generic you want this? Are you open to using **cats**? Or you want a vanilla **Scala** solution? Finally, what have you done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assumed:

```
val a = List(Left(1), Left(2), Left(3)) // for example
```

Then following will return a `Left[List[Int]]`:

```
Left(a.map(_.value))
// Left(List(1, 2, 3))
```

Then you can extract the values out of the list, which I don't thin is generally a good idea.

Comment: This will fail if there's a `Right` in the list also. Also, if the compiler thinks the list contains `Either`s instead of `Left`s

Comment: @randbw Yeah but in the question every element wan of type Left [_], you can also specify the type like so: val a: List [Left [Int, _] ] = ...

Comment: @randbw which of course why would anyone want to use such thing? anyway